# Postgresql database structure for multiple measuring stations

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I am planning on building a database with PostgreSQL to learn about databases and the usage of geospatial queries.

The data I use are multiple measuring stations that have data for different time periods, but all on a base of daily values. Every station has a specific station number, spatial information, and different values that it measures.

My idea about the structure would be that I use one schema for the station information that contains one table with the station numbers and the spatial information.

For each station, I would then create an own schema with a name as

> sta_STN

where **STN** would be the station's number. Here I wanted to split the information I have to different tables to evaluate it more comfortably later as every station is measuring different values.

```
schema   | table
---------|---------------------------------------------
stations | all (station number, spatial information)
sta_STN  | general (date, other information)
         | values of kind 1 (date, measuring information regarding kind 1)
         | values of kind 2 (date, measuring information regarding kind 2)
         | values of kind 3 (date, measuring information regarding kind 3)
```

All tables in every sta_STN schema would have the primary key of the date as it is guaranteed to be unique, although there might be gaps because of errors.

In the end, I want to evaluate the values for each station for a specific period. The connection between the different stations is most likely not relevant to me.

I was wondering if this structure makes sense as it doesn't provide a connection between the data and the stations via a key and I might end up with about 15k of stations so 15k schemas as well.

Any suggestions or ideas on how to set it up?

Comment: Don't do that. Read about [Data Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and create your database with a proper design. This one you propose will be a maintainability nightmare for anyone who works with it. 15k schemas??? Man I can't even imagine such horrendous thing to work with. Follow the @dmfay's answer advice. Normalize your data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that. You'll be miserable.

Tables group data of the same type. Station information is data of the same type. That means a `stations` table with the appropriate fields to represent the number and location.

Measurements are -- theoretically -- also data of the same type, so think about the exact data you're capturing. Try to develop a schema for a single table which can include every possible measurement from any station. Don't be afraid to have multiple columns: I used to work on assembly line test stands where a single "measurement" consisted of multiple torque and angle combinations represented as columns `torque_1`, `angle_1`, `torque_2`, `angle_2`, and so on at a given timestamp for a given station. If your stations are measuring completely different things, it gets trickier. Whether you'd be better off splitting into different measurement tables or genericizing `value_n` and `unit_n` columns depends on your exact situation, so I can't speak to that.

You may be tempted to factor out "submeasurements" consisting of a table with columns for a single value and unit; this is a trap, called the entity-attribute-value or EAV (anti)pattern. It is extremely difficult to query EAV data. You will need to have one row per measurement in order to be able to query it effectively.

Comment: If I get you right, I would have two tables at the end `stations` and `measurements`. The first one is clear, but would I really want to put all measurements data in the second one as I got like 15k stations and each station might easily reach 40k timesteps? Will this not lead to performance issues when I try to evaluate the data?

Comment: It's doable, but might stress your system or require more detailed tuning. Indexing will help, but some queries could still run long. Generally it's best to err on the side of simplicity in your schema until you can prove you need to do something more complicated, so it's worth running a load test if you're unsure. You might also look at databases like Cassandra which are specifically optimized for this sort of use case.

Comment: Alright. If performance is too bad, I would probably start a measurement table for each station. As the station number would be the same for every row, I guess I would drop it. Therefore the only linking between the measurement table and the stations would be via the name of the table. Is this a suitable way or will I most likely run into problems with this?

Comment: That makes ad-hoc querying much more difficult, since you need to know ahead of time which sta_xyz_measurements tables to join to your queries. This may or may not matter for what you're doing. If it doesn't, you'll probably be fine.